# Unexpected behavior from xgboost in Python with Custom Evaluation Function

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, xgboost

I am using xgboost with a Custom Evaluation Function and I would like to implement Early Stopping setting a limit of 150 rounds.

I am getting back 4 evaluation metrics than the expected 2 and I do not know how to interpret them.  Moreover I am not sure how to activate early stopping setting a limit as well (e.g., 150 rounds).

For a reproducible example:

```
import numpy as np

def F1_eval_gen(preds, labels):
    t = np.arange(0, 1, 0.005)
    f = np.repeat(0, 200)
    results = np.vstack([t, f]).T
    # assuming labels only containing 0's and 1's
    n_pos_examples = sum(labels)
    if n_pos_examples == 0:
        n_pos_examples = 1

    for i in range(200):
        pred_indexes = (preds >= results[i, 0])
        TP = sum(labels[pred_indexes])
        FP = len(labels[pred_indexes]) - TP
        precision = 0
        recall = TP / n_pos_examples

        if (FP + TP) > 0:
            precision = TP / (FP + TP)

        if (precision + recall > 0):
            F1 = 2 * precision * recall / (precision + recall)
        else:
            F1 = 0
        results[i, 1] = F1
    return (max(results[:, 1]))

def F1_eval(preds, dtrain):
    res = F1_eval_gen(preds, dtrain.get_label())
    return 'f1_err', 1-res

from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import *

skl_data = datasets.load_breast_cancer()

X = skl_data.data

y = skl_data.target

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2)

scale_pos_weight = sum(y_train == 0)/sum(y_train == 1)


base_score = sum(y_train == 1)/len(y_train)


max_depth = 6
learning_rate = 0.1
gamma = 0
min_child_weight = 1
subsample = 0.8
colsample_bytree = 0.8
colsample_bylevel = 1
reg_alpha = 0
reg_lambda = 1


clf = xgb.XGBClassifier(max_depth= max_depth, learning_rate= learning_rate,silent=False, objective='binary:logistic', \
                  booster='gbtree', n_jobs=8, nthread=None, gamma=gamma, min_child_weight=min_child_weight, max_delta_step=0, \
                  subsample= subsample, colsample_bytree=colsample_bytree, colsample_bylevel=colsample_bylevel, \
                         reg_alpha= reg_alpha, reg_lambda=1, scale_pos_weight= scale_pos_weight, base_score= base_score)

clf.fit(X_train, y_train,
eval_set=[(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test)], eval_metric= F1_eval, verbose=True)

..................
[94]    validation_0-error:0    validation_1-error:0.035088 validation_0-f1_err:0   validation_1-f1_err:0.018634
[95]    validation_0-error:0    validation_1-error:0.035088 validation_0-f1_err:0   validation_1-f1_err:0.018634
[96]    validation_0-error:0    validation_1-error:0.035088 validation_0-f1_err:0   validation_1-f1_err:0.018634
[97]    validation_0-error:0    validation_1-error:0.035088 validation_0-f1_err:0   validation_1-f1_err:0.018634
[98]    validation_0-error:0    validation_1-error:0.035088 validation_0-f1_err:0   validation_1-f1_err:0.018634
[99]    validation_0-error:0    validation_1-error:0.035088 validation_0-f1_err:0   validation_1-f1_err:0.018634
```

---

```
clf = xgb.XGBClassifier(max_depth= max_depth, niterations = 1000, learning_rate= learning_rate,silent=False, \
                        objective='binary:logistic', booster='gbtree', n_jobs=8, nthread=None, gamma=gamma,\
                        min_child_weight=min_child_weight, max_delta_step=0, \
                  subsample= subsample, colsample_bytree=colsample_bytree, colsample_bylevel=colsample_bylevel, \
                         reg_alpha= reg_alpha, reg_lambda=1, scale_pos_weight= scale_pos_weight, base_score= base_score)

clf.fit(X_train, y_train, early_stopping_rounds= 25,
eval_set=[(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test)], eval_metric= F1_eval, verbose=True)

[0] validation_0-error:0.386813 validation_1-error:0.315789 validation_0-f1_err:0.032609    validation_1-f1_err:0.031847
Multiple eval metrics have been passed: 'validation_1-f1_err' will be used for early stopping.

Will train until validation_1-f1_err hasn't improved in 25 rounds.
[1] validation_0-error:0.131868 validation_1-error:0.078947 validation_0-f1_err:0.016216    validation_1-f1_err:0.031056
[2] validation_0-error:0.048352 validation_1-error:0.052632 validation_0-f1_err:0.012522    validation_1-f1_err:0.037037
[3] validation_0-error:0.032967 validation_1-error:0.04386  validation_0-f1_err:0.008977    validation_1-f1_err:0.031447
[4] validation_0-error:0.01978  validation_1-error:0.04386  validation_0-f1_err:0.010753    validation_1-f1_err:0.031447
[5] validation_0-error:0.015385 validation_1-error:0.035088 validation_0-f1_err:0.008977    validation_1-f1_err:0.025316
[6] validation_0-error:0.013187 validation_1-error:0.04386  validation_0-f1_err:0.010676    validation_1-f1_err:0.025316
[7] validation_0-error:0.017582 validation_1-error:0.04386  validation_0-f1_err:0.010638    validation_1-f1_err:0.018868
[8] validation_0-error:0.013187 validation_1-error:0.04386  validation_0-f1_err:0.008913    validation_1-f1_err:0.025
[9] validation_0-error:0.008791 validation_1-error:0.04386  validation_0-f1_err:0.007143    validation_1-f1_err:0.025
[10]    validation_0-error:0.010989 validation_1-error:0.04386  validation_0-f1_err:0.007143    validation_1-f1_err:0.025
[11]    validation_0-error:0.008791 validation_1-error:0.04386  validation_0-f1_err:0.007143    validation_1-f1_err:0.025
[12]    validation_0-error:0.008791 validation_1-error:0.052632 validation_0-f1_err:0.007143    validation_1-f1_err:0.025
[13]    validation_0-error:0.008791 validation_1-error:0.052632 validation_0-f1_err:0.007117    validation_1-f1_err:0.025
[14]    validation_0-error:0.008791 validation_1-error:0.052632 validation_0-f1_err:0.005348    validation_1-f1_err:0.018868
[15]    validation_0-error:0.008791 validation_1-error:0.052632 validation_0-f1_err:0.005348    validation_1-f1_err:0.018868
[16]    validation_0-error:0.008791 validation_1-error:0.052632 validation_0-f1_err:0.005348    validation_1-f1_err:0.018868
[17]    validation_0-error:0.008791 validation_1-error:0.052632 validation_0-f1_err:0.005348    validation_1-f1_err:0.018868
[18]    validation_0-error:0.008791 validation_1-error:0.052632 validation_0-f1_err:0.005348    validation_1-f1_err:0.018868
[19]    validation_0-error:0.008791 validation_1-error:0.052632 validation_0-f1_err:0.005348    validation_1-f1_err:0.018868
[20]    validation_0-error:0.008791 validation_1-error:0.052632 validation_0-f1_err:0.005348    validation_1-f1_err:0.018868
[21]    validation_0-error:0.006593 validation_1-error:0.052632 validation_0-f1_err:0.005348    validation_1-f1_err:0.018868
[22]    validation_0-error:0.006593 validation_1-error:0.052632 validation_0-f1_err:0.003571    validation_1-f1_err:0.018868
[23]    validation_0-error:0.006593 validation_1-error:0.052632 validation_0-f1_err:0.003571    validation_1-f1_err:0.018868
[24]    validation_0-error:0.006593 validation_1-error:0.052632 validation_0-f1_err:0.003571    validation_1-f1_err:0.018868
[25]    validation_0-error:0.006593 validation_1-error:0.052632 validation_0-f1_err:0.003571    validation_1-f1_err:0.018868
[26]    validation_0-error:0.004396 validation_1-error:0.052632 validation_0-f1_err:0.003571    validation_1-f1_err:0.018868
[27]    validation_0-error:0.004396 validation_1-error:0.052632 validation_0-f1_err:0.003584    validation_1-f1_err:0.018868
[28]    validation_0-error:0.004396 validation_1-error:0.052632 validation_0-f1_err:0.003584    validation_1-f1_err:0.018868
[29]    validation_0-error:0.004396 validation_1-error:0.052632 validation_0-f1_err:0.003571    validation_1-f1_err:0.018868
[30]    validation_0-error:0.004396 validation_1-error:0.052632 validation_0-f1_err:0.001789    validation_1-f1_err:0.018868
[31]    validation_0-error:0.004396 validation_1-error:0.052632 validation_0-f1_err:0.001789    validation_1-f1_err:0.018868
[32]    validation_0-error:0.004396 validation_1-error:0.052632 validation_0-f1_err:0.001789    validation_1-f1_err:0.018868
Stopping. Best iteration:
[7] validation_0-error:0.017582 validation_1-error:0.04386  validation_0-f1_err:0.010638    validation_1-f1_err:0.018868

XGBClassifier(base_score=0.6131868131868132, booster='gbtree',
       colsample_bylevel=1, colsample_bytree=0.8, gamma=0,
       learning_rate=0.1, max_delta_step=0, max_depth=6,
       min_child_weight=1, missing=None, n_estimators=100, n_jobs=8,
       niterations=1000, nthread=None, objective='binary:logistic',
       random_state=0, reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=1,
       scale_pos_weight=0.6308243727598566, seed=None, silent=False,
       subsample=0.8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you get 4 evaluation matrices because somehow xgboost adding another evaluation metric to your `eval_set`. personally, I'm using the core xgboost and not the scikit warp up. So if you want to learn more, read about it in the documentation.

for early_stopping, you have to set `n_estimators=1000` (or how many iterations you want) as a parameter in `xgb.XGBClassifier`

And set `early_stopping_rounds=50` (or what ever value you want) in `clf.fit`.
[Here's the documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBClassifier.fit).

---

### A quick overview on what early stopping is doing

early stopping comes to decide when you need to stop boosting the algorithm to avoid over fitting. it is doing so by evaluating your `tuple` `(X_test, y_test)` you defined in `eval_set`. early_stopping will stop your boosting if the evaluation error hasn't decrease over *50* iterations.

Comment: I passed the early_stopping_rounds argument as you indicated but it was ignored.  I.e., clf.fit(X_train, y_train, early_stopping_rounds= 200,
eval_set=[(X_train, y_train), (X_dev, y_dev)], eval_metric= F1_eval, verbose=True)

Comment: Show me how it was ignored. Print the output

Comment: Perhaps it was not ignored.  It waited to see if the performance will improve.  But still should n't it have stopped earlier?  The best iteration was the 7th. How about the multiple evaluation metrics?

Comment: Don't know.. Read in the documentation. xgboost or the scikit-learn wrap up probably adds a default evaluation metric corresponding with your objective function.

Comment: OK thanks Eran.  I have read the documentation but perhaps I am missing this point.